# Grab current URL anchor and run X

Tags: jquery, anchor

I am using a coda slider plugin and when you click different segments, it will then load:

site.com/#1, site.com/#4

Is there a way to check for that using jQuery, then run a function. I have a slider with 4 parts

sunrise, day, sunrise, night

And on night ,I want to overlay a transparent PNG. And it is #4, so when the user clicks that and #4 is in the URL as an anchor, overlay.

I understand all the other code, but not sure if it is possible to check for that anchor?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [jQuery History plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/history), but it will be a lot simpler if you can find a way to extend the Coda slider plugin to notify your code directly.